# Proof involving matrix inverse of: $\|A^{-1}\|_\infty \ge \frac{\|U^{-1}\|_\infty}{n}$ 

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working to prove the following $$\|A^{-1}\|_\infty \ge \frac{\|U^{-1}\|_\infty}{n}$$ where $PA=LU$.

Comment: You can LaTeX here. Just enclose it within `$...$`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do $$PA = LU,$$ I assume you are doing a partial pivoting. If so, the elements of $L$ are less than unity with the diagonal entries being $1$. This means $\|L\|_{\infty} \leq n$. (Because the infinity norm of a matrix is the largest row sum of the absolute values and in each row of $L$ all the elements are atmost $1$.) Hence, $$U^{-1} = A^{-1}P^{-1}L$$ i.e. $$\|U^{-1}\|_{\infty} = \|A^{-1}P^{-1}L\|_{\infty} \leq \|A^{-1}\|_{\infty} \|P^{-1}\|_{\infty} \|L\|_{\infty} = \|A^{-1}\|_{\infty} \|L\|_{\infty} \leq n \|A^{-1}\|_{\infty}$$ Note that $\|P\|_{\infty} = 1$ since all the row sum is $1$.
Hence, we get $$ \|A^{-1}\|_{\infty} \geq \frac{\|U^{-1}\|_{\infty}}{n}.$$

Comment: This is  great thanks a lot! I was focusing on relating the absolute row sum of inv(A) to that of inv(U) and totally missed the property of L that completes the inequality!